# Mat-tree create a tree with values to display and ids

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I'm learning how to use mat-tree following the docs, but now I need to use a data source tree that has not only strings defined in it, because when I click a node I need to know its id.
[This is the stackblitz of my project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5wsql).
Basically I need to use this tree with checkboxes that I've built following the docs, but now my data source is this:

```
const TREE_DATA:TodoItemNode = {
  item: "First item",
  children: [{
    item: 'Second item',
    children:[
      {
        item: "Third item",
        id: 3
      }
    ],
      id:2
    }],
  id:1
  }
```

So I want to display as text the value of item and then get the "id" when that node is clicked. Currently I can't make it work and I only see these tree nodes:

[image]

Is there a working example for data as JSON, with properties etc. as I want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really I beleive the example about tree-view is more complex. Imagine you has some like

```
const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: "Fruit",
    children: [
      { name: "Apple", id: 1 },
      { name: "Banana", id: 2 },
      { name: "Fruit loops", id: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Vegetables",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Green",
        children: [
          { name: "Broccoli", id: 4 },
          { name: "Brussel sprouts", id: 5 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Orange",
        children: [{ name: "Pumpkins", id: 6 }, { name: "Carrots", id: 7 }]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

If you add to your FoodNode interface some auxiliars properties: selected,parent and indeterminate

```
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  id?: number;
  selected?: boolean;
  indeterminate?:boolean;
  parent?:FoodNode
  children?: FoodNode[];
}
```

The key here is know the "parent", so, when we toogle one check, ask about his parent

```
  setParent(data, parent) {
    data.parent = parent;
    if (data.children) {
      data.children.forEach(x => {
        this.setParent(x, data);
      });
    }
  }
```

You can write an .html like

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
          <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node" 
            (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle($event.checked,node)" 
            [checked]="node.selected"
>{{node.name}}</mat-checkbox>
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="node.selected"
                  [indeterminate]="node.indeterminate && !node.selected"
                  (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle($event.checked,node)">
            {{node.name}}</mat-checkbox>
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Anothers functions are

```
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<FoodNode>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
    Object.keys(this.dataSource.data).forEach(x => {
      this.setParent(this.dataSource.data[x], null);
    });
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) =>
    !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  checkAllParents(node) {
    if (node.parent) {
      const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node.parent);
      node.parent.selected=descendants.every(child => child.selected);
      node.parent.indeterminate=descendants.some(child => child.selected);
      this.checkAllParents(node.parent);
    }
  }

  todoItemSelectionToggle(checked, node) {
    node.selected = checked;
    if (node.children) {
      node.children.forEach(x => {
        this.todoItemSelectionToggle(checked, x);
      });
    }
    this.checkAllParents(node);
  }
}
  submit() {
    let result = [];
    this.dataSource.data.forEach(node => {
      result = result.concat(
        this.treeControl
          .getDescendants(node)
          .filter(x => x.selected && x.id)
          .map(x => x.id)
      );
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
```

The stackblitz, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4wnp35?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts)

Comment: This is really helpful, but I need one more thing here. Can you give the example with initially selected nodes? Not all only few of them with same data.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4wnp35-knmkqr?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.tsAdding a stackblitz example using the above approach to set initially selected nodes.