# Tree like checkbox and search filter implementation in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

**What I have:**

I have implemented a tree like structure with checkbox selection and search filter. The hierarchy is of fixed 3 levels(`Parent->Intermediate->Child`). Selecting checkboxes is working perfectly fine(with all feature including indeterminate sign on checkbox when some of nodes selected or tick sign when all childs are selected).

I have also applied a search filter on the tree structured data with a custom angular pipe.

The problem happens when I apply search filter, the selection of checkboxes misbehaves. Also it do not get selected. The indeterminate sign
also not working as expected.

A very good reference is this: https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/filtering, although I can't use this library, but I wanted to have exact similar feature.

**My requirement is that user should able to filter the nodes and select the node**

**What I tried:**

I have created this Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpz74p?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts). Please have a look at this.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: blitz is great, but when asking a question, you should include most relevant code in your question with some brief outline of what the pieces are doing

Comment: I'm unclear on what your actual goal / expected behavior is here. What should happen to the data and the checkboxes when something is checked?

Comment: @bryan60 As I mentioned in the question, I want to implement similar feature like this https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/filtering. Although my code is very redundant(how better can I optimize the code), also when I search for any node and select it after clearing the input selection goes away.

Comment: A similar library isn't as helpful as you explaining your expected behavior and requirements.  Providing that will get you the best answers possible.

Comment: why dont you check library code and use that?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the library for that.https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tree. What was the reason that you have to develop it by yourself?

Answer (score 4):

why not use a mat-tree? based in [this SO about tree-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378671/mat-tree-create-a-tree-with-values-to-display-and-ids/58384543#58384543)

We need two recursive functions:

```
setChildOk(text: string, node: any) {
    node.forEach(x => {
      x.ok = x.name.indexOf(text) >= 0;
      if (x.parent) this.setParentOk(text, x.parent,x.ok);
      if (x.children) this.setChildOk(text, x.children);
    });
  }
  setParentOk(text, node,ok) {
    node.ok = node.ok || ok || node.name.indexOf(text)>=0;
    if (node.parent) this.setParentOk(text, node.parent,node.ok);
  }
```

We can add an input "search" and make a function

```
 <input matInput [ngModel]="search" 
       (ngModelChange)="search=$event;setChildOk($event,dataSource.data)">
```

Well, now, we show the nodes is node.ok or if !search

```
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle 
      [style.display]="!search || node.ok?'block':'none'">
```

And

```
<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" 
          [style.display]="!search || node.ok?'block':'none'">
```

See in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4wnp35-cyp2n1?file=app/tree-nested-overview-example.html)

Comment: How can you do it so if searching for 'Fruit' in your example you show all children of 'Fruit Loops'?